# c++ std::unique_ptr in a loop - memory leaks

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, c++17, visual-studio-2019, unique-ptr

Is unique_ptr used properly in this loop?
Each time this while loop ends, the overall heap size increases slightly. As I investigate the code with debug tool of Visual studio, it seems that the unique_ptr object "task" is not being released, causing memory leak.
I thought unique_ptr memory would be released after the end of brace, in this case, the end of each loop or the end brace of try-catch. Is there some misunderstanding?

My env: VisualStudio2019, MSVC, C++17

###### Update(2023/10/6)

- I updated the code as below.
- tried to make minimum reproduction, but I could't make it for some reason. Therefore this code works properly without memory leak. The only deferences are header file of each class and class name. Im so confused.
- [Here's screenshot of debug tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQKhg.png). I wonder why this _container_proxy[], TaskFactory[] and TaskImplA[] pile up constantly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

class MessageTask {
public:
    MessageTask() {};
    MessageTask(char*& message) {};
    virtual ~MessageTask() {};
    void execute() {
        decide_task();
        do_task();
    }
    virtual void decide_task() = 0;
    virtual void do_task() = 0;
};

class TaskImpl : public MessageTask{
private:
    char* message;
public:
    TaskImpl() {};
    TaskImpl(char*& message) { this->message = message; };
    ~TaskImpl() {};
    void decide_task() { std::cout << message << std::endl;  return; };
    void do_task() { return; };
};

class TaskFactory {
public:
    TaskFactory() {};
    ~TaskFactory() {};
    std::unique_ptr<MessageTask> create_message_task(char*& message, int& sender) {
        if (sender == 2000) {
            return std::make_unique<TaskImpl>(message);
        }
        return nullptr;
    };
};

class UdpComm {
private:
    SOCKET m_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in m_address;
    WSADATA m_wsadata;

public:
    UdpComm() {};
    ~UdpComm() {};
    struct sockaddr_in m_address_send_from;

    void initialize_receiver() {
        WSACleanup();
        int startup_result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &this->m_wsadata);
        this->m_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        this->m_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
        this->m_address.sin_port = htons(5001);
        this->m_address.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        int wsa_result = bind(this->m_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&this->m_address, sizeof(this->m_address));
    };

    int receive_sync(char* buffer_ptr, const size_t buffer_size, size_t& rx_size)
    {
        int sockaddr_in_size = sizeof(this->m_address_send_from);
        int receive_result = recvfrom(this->m_socket, (char*)buffer_ptr, (int)buffer_size, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&m_address_send_from, &sockaddr_in_size);
        rx_size = (size_t)receive_result;
        return 0;
    }
};

class Receiver {
public:
    int udp_receive(UdpComm& uc_rcv) {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                char buffer[1024];
                char* buffer_ptr = buffer;
                size_t buffer_size = sizeof(buffer);
                size_t rx_size = 0;
                uc_rcv.receive_sync(buffer_ptr, buffer_size, rx_size);
                int port = ntohs(uc_rcv.m_address_send_from.sin_port);
                auto factory = std::make_unique<TaskFactory>();
                auto task = factory->create_message_task(buffer_ptr, port);
                task->execute();
            }
            catch (const std::exception& ex)
            {
                std::cerr << "[ERROR] " << ex.what() << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    auto uc_rcv = std::make_unique<UdpComm>();
    uc_rcv->initialize_receiver();
    Receiver receiver;
    receiver.udp_receive(*uc_rcv);
}
```

I investigated with debug tool of Visual Studio 2019 and it showed the heap size increased. Also, I commented out the following process in the task->execute() but still memory leak happened.

Comment: I'm not sure how we could answer without knowing what `create_message_task` and `execute` do. Do you see the leak without those lines commented out?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Your unique pointer is not helping here at all. You make it once (and somewhere very late in the shutdown of the program it gets destroyed). So it is in no way responsible for your leak (and thus should not be part of your question). The leak must come from create_message_task. As a Side note I would just make the factory a member variable of the Receiver class (and let it share the classes lifecycle)

Comment: *"the overall heap size increases slightly"* Not necessary a memory leak, memory fragmentation might also happen...

Comment: Why is the factory pointer `static`? Is the factory class (its `create_message_task()`) thead-safe? If not, then `static` has zero benefit and can only hurt you in a multi-threaded environment with multiple instances of the function “running”. `udp_receive` sounds like something asynchronous and/or multi-threaded.

Comment: The _minimal reproducible example_ aside, please provide a `valgrind` output showing the leak. That can shed much more light on what exactly happens.

Comment: I updated the question field. I don't know why but I could'nt reproduce the memory leak with above code.  The only deferences between the real code and the posted code are header file of each class and class name.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Oddly enough, commenting out the process of create_message_task() and execute() also causes a memory leak in the orifinal code.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek Thank you for the advice. I modified the factory obj as non-static.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek Also I added the screenshot of debug tool. It seems that _Container_proxy[], TaskFactory[], TaskImplA[] obj piles up.

Comment: `TaskImpl` assumes that `message` points to a NUL-terminated string. But the program passes a pointer to a buffer that's not guaranteed to be NUL-terminated.

Comment: `factory->create_message_task(buffer_ptr, port);` returns a NULL pointer unless `port == 2000`.  The program doesn't check for null, but goes ahead and calls a method through that pointer.